# Inserting a new column with date format in Python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataframe, df, where I am wanting to insert a new column named data in specific format.

df:

```
     Name      ID
  
     Kelly     A
     John      B
```

Desired output:

```
   Date           Name      ID
  
  2019-10-01     Kelly     A
  2019-10-01     John      B
```

This is what I am doing:

```
 df['2019-10-01'] =  date
```

I am still researching this. Any insight is helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with

```
 df['date'] = '2019-10-01'
```

Comment: Hi @ben_yo, is there a way to specify the location of the new column, such as iloc[0]  (I wish for the new column to be the first column)

Comment: @Lynnette https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.insert.html

Comment: @Lynnette `df.insert(0,'Date',value='2019-10-01')
`